# Conditions for adding to the list variable

Tags: python, list, loops

Below you can see the sequence commands which simply add elements from the `dirs` list to some other list `new` using special built-in function:

```
new = Trajectory(os.path.join(path, dirs[0]))
new.addFile(os.path.join(path, dirs[1]))
new.addFile(os.path.join(path, dirs[2]))
new.addFile(os.path.join(path, dirs[3]))
```

I need to simplify this script placing all `new.addFile` in a loop like:

```
for element in dirs:
 new.addFile(os.path.join(path, element)
```

The question: how to add some rule which exclude `dirs[0]` to adding using this loop on the first step? In my case `dirs[0]`  is already always present within `new` so I need not to add it again while looping the first list.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) the `dirs` list to skip the first item:

```
for element in dirs[1:]:
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for i in lst[1:]:
...     i
...
2
3
4
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is really straightforward:

```
for element in dirs[1:]:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1, len(dirs)):
    new.addFile(os.path.join(path, dirs[i])
```

This just starts the loop at 1 rather than 0.